# Invoke rake task from ActiveRecord observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Can I do the following?

```
def ModelObserver < ActiveRecord

   def after_save
     Rake::Task[name].invoke
   end

end
```

At the moment, this returns the following error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'name'
```

Any idea?

Comment: What Rake task are you trying to invoke? Is it one that you've written yourself?

Comment: Tasks that I have written and tasks written by others, e.g. rake thinking_sphinx:reindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the system command :

```
def ModelObserver < ActiveRecord

   def after_save
     system "rake #{name}"
   end

end
```

Comment: This is probably slow as hell as it spawns the complete rails stack. You don't want to do that in an observer... Especially you REALLY don't want to do that in an after_save hook...

Comment: Just watched Railscast 127 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background). Putting an & at the end of the call, will force the process to run in background. system "rake #{name} &"

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [delayed job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or similar plugin to handle background execution. In observer (or controller) just notify background job daemon, that it should take care of some action, instead of running this task directly.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails3 if you still want to call rake task like this:

```
Rake::Task[name].invoke
```

you have to put

```
[Application].load_tasks
```

before invoke command, where application is your application name. For example I had to put

```
Ead::Application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to load the Rake environment first, and the Rakefile. I would not try to invoke the fullblown command line to do that. You probably need to use "import" as can be found in the [Rake API](http://rake.rubyforge.org/)