# is it possible to embed rake into an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

My app has a complicated set of dependencies -- some information comes from user input, some comes from remote sites via delayed_job -- expressible as a directed acyclic graph.  I was all set to write a simple dependency mechanism to traverse the graph, but it occurs to me: Rake does this already, and I shouldn't re-invent the wheel.

Usually rake takes its declarations in a standalone rake file and is run from the command line.  Instead, is it possible to write the declarations in a library or model file and run rake from within the app?  (To make it clear: I would NOT be using rake here for long-running tasks, I just want it for its ability to define and traverse a dependency graph.)

This loads without error:

```
require 'rake'
class MyClass
  task :clean do
    puts 'cleaning'
  end
end
```

... but it's not clear how to invoke it, or create tasks in namespaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment:

**From Rake:**

`Rake::Task#execute`

http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Task.html

**From term or cmd:**

Windows:
`system('start rake doc:app')`

Linux:
`system('rake doc:app')`

Here's a discussion at ruby-forum:

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/196210

Here's a related StackOverflow question / answer using the system call:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3021805

Comment: Hi @Roxberry: if you read the OP, term and cmd are not relevant.  And I already know about Rake::Task#execute.  The code snippet I gave defines a task, but how do you get a handle on the task in order to execute it?